# gtk paned handle fixed lower half

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'd like to fixed the lower half of the paned, the second childs height to a x pixels. When the window is resized it must stay at x pixels.

You would think it would be easy but it doesn't seem to be the case. The problem I'm having is that when I record the position of the handle then try to set it in the resize handler, it triggers a handle position changed event again and either because it is wonky or I'm not calculating it right, it gets more and more off or the window just gets screwed up and doesn't even redraw completely sometimes.

The default method seems to keep the first child the same size.. I need similar behavior but for the second child.

Comment: Did you play with GtkPaned resize and shrink child properties?

Comment: Of course. I might have missed something but I couldn't get it to work. Remember that I also want to allow it to be resized by the user. I've moved on from using it because it was a pain to get working right. Still would be nice to know how to get it to work.

Comment: "it triggers a handle position changed event". You can disable the effect of your changing the position by calling `g_signal_handler_block ()` and `...unblock` functions.